# Once submit form when there are multiple tabs inside the form and in each of tabs have table input(which able add table row)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, tabs

Let me explain the situation here. I have a page called travel.php. I want to submit a form in the travel.php. In this form, it contains few input at the top, and after that below it have a 2 tabs (hotel tab and airplane tab). In each tabs have a table input (which able to add row).

Below is an example (not fully. Just showing the flow) of submit FORM code which is working, but this code i only include one tabs which only got one table (which able to add row). Based on the code below what can i do if i have a 2 tabs (hotel tab and airplane tab). In each tabs have a table input (which able to add row).

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['travel']))
{
//Do smth
//List $_POST

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["merchant"]); $i++)
    {
        $merchant   = $_POST["merchant"][$i];
        $remark = $_POST["remark"][$i];
        $docno  = $_POST["docno"][$i];
        $date   = $_POST["date"][$i];
        $category   = $_POST["category"][$i];
        $claim_amount   = $_POST["claim_amount"][$i];

        $targetPath="upload/";
        $file = $targetPath.rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['bill_image']['name'][$i];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['bill_image']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_basename = substr($file, 0, strripos($file, '.'));
        move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$file);

        $save_new_record = "INSERT INTO `report`...";

        $stmt5 = $mysqli->prepare($save_new_record);

        $stmt5->bind_param('ssiis', $reportName, $report_number, $euser);


        if ($stmt5->execute() == false){
                echo 'Fifth query failed: ' . $mysqli->error;
                }
                $stmt5->close();
        }

        $title          = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
        $mode           = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mode"]);
        $from_date      = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["from_date"]);
        $to_date            = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["to_date"]);
        $timefrom       = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["timefrom"]);
        $timeto         = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["timeto"]);

        $save_report_s = "INSERT INTO `traveling` () VALUES ()";
        $save_report_ss = "INSERT INTO `report_s`() VALUES ()";

        $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare($save_report_s);
        $stmt6 = $mysqli->prepare($save_report_ss);

        $stmt3->bind_param('', $);
        $stmt6->bind_param('', $);
        if ($stmt6->execute() == false){
                echo 'gl A query failed: ' . $mysqli->error;
            } else {
                if ($stmt3->execute() == false){
                    echo 'gl B query failed: ' . $mysqli->error;    
                }
                $stmt3->close();            
            }
            $stmt6->close();
}
?>
```

i hope someone can give me hints how i can single submit a form where inside a form have a few input field at the top (will insert into database table called "TRAVELING")and at bottom have 2 tabs, in those two tabs have it owns table input (dynamically add rows table).. The table in each tabs have a slightly different attributes but it will be insert into same database TABLE called "RECORD". This i found a short and easy to view example (which involve one table only)  [CLICK](http://demo.techstream.org/Dynamic-Form-Processing-with-PHP) but my problem is how can i submit form when there are two tabs at below and in each of tab have its own table.