# Submit two table of data in one form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a form which contain two table. Each of the table able to add table row. which mean when submit a form using isset $_POST by using "for" right? the things that i concern about is how to submit a single form which contain two table (both of them have function add table row) in single database table. Both of table contain slightly different attribute but in the same database table. i was searching this for a week and didnt found solution yet. I only able to submit a form which contain one table (which have add table row). How about if there is two table but insert into same database table?

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
        //others
        $merchant   = $_POST['merchant'];
        $remark = $_POST['remark'];
        $docno  = $_POST['docno'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $claim_amount   = $_POST['claim_amount'];

        //airfare
        $airline    = $_POST["airline"];
        $origin = $_POST["origin"];
        $destination = $_POST["destination"];
        $descript = $_POST["desc"];
        $docno_air = $_POST["docno_air"];
        $category_air = $_POST["category_air"];
        $claim_amount_fare  = $_POST["claim_amount_fare"];

        $email = $ColUser['Email'];
        $euser  = $_SESSION['UserId'];
        $reportName = $_POST['reportname'];
        $start_date = date("Y-m-d");
        $status="open";
        $purpose = $_POST["purpose"];

        //get approval
        $getapproval = "SELECT * FROM `approve_by` WHERE `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['UserId']."'";
        $approvalget = mysqli_query($mysqli,$getapproval);
        $appid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($approvalget);
        $app1 = $appid['approval_1'];
        $app2 = $appid['approval_2'];
        $app3 = $appid['approval_3'];

        //generate travel id
        $travelprefix= "SELECT * FROM `prefix` WHERE `description` = 'Travel'";
        $result_travel = mysqli_query($mysqli, $travelprefix);
        $travel_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_travel);

        $travel_pre = $travel_info['prefix'];
        $travel_old_num = $travel_info['running_number'] + 1;
        $travel_new = sprintf("%05d", $travel_old_num);
        $travel_date_append = date('mY');
        $travel_number = $travel_pre."-".$travel_date_append."-".$travel_new;

        //generate report id
        $reportprefix= "SELECT * FROM `prefix` WHERE `description` = 'REPORT'";
        $result_report = mysqli_query($mysqli, $reportprefix);
        $report_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_report);

        $report_pre = $report_info['prefix'];
        $report_old_num = $report_info['running_number'] + 1;
        $report_new = sprintf("%05d", $report_old_num);
        $report_date_append = date('mY');
        $report_number = $report_pre."-".$report_date_append."-".$report_new;

    if (!empty($_POST['airline']))
    {

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["airline"]); $i++){

        $airline    = $_POST["airline"][$i];
        $origin = $_POST["origin"][$i];
        $destination = $_POST["destination"][$i];
        $descript = $_POST["desc"][$i];
        $docno_air = $_POST["docno_air"][$i];
        $category_air = $_POST["category_air"][$i];
        $claim_amount_fare  = $_POST["claim_amount_fare"][$i];

        //$upload_dir = 'upload';
        //$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $targetPaths="upload/";
        $filefare = $targetPaths.rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['bill_image_air']['name'][$i];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['bill_image_air']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_basename = substr($filefare, 0, strripos($filefare, '.'));
        //$flink='http://localhost/new_exp/'.$file;
        move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$filefare);

        $mrecordprefix= "SELECT * FROM `prefix` WHERE `description` = 'Category'";
        $mresult_record = mysqli_query($mysqli, $mrecordprefix);
        $mrecord_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mresult_record);

        $mrecord_pre = $mrecord_info['prefix'];
        $mrecord_old_num = $mrecord_info['running_number'] + 1;
        $mrecord_new = sprintf("%05d", $mrecord_old_num);
        $mrecord_date_append = date('mY');
        $mrecord_number = $mrecord_pre."-".$mrecord_date_append."-".$mrecord_new;

        $save_running_records = "UPDATE `prefix` SET `running_number`=? WHERE `description` = 'Category'";
        $save_running_report = "UPDATE `prefix` SET `running_number`=? WHERE `description` = 'Report'";
        $save_running_travel = "UPDATE `prefix` SET `running_number`=? WHERE `description` = 'Travel'";
        $save_new_record = "INSERT INTO `report`(`reportname`, `report_ref`, `UserId`, `CategoryId`, `travel_record`, `remark`, `claim_amount`, `bill_image`, `bill_image_type`, `docno`, `origin`, `airline`, `destination`, `email_from`, `approval_1`, `approval_2`, `approval_3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $save_count = "INSERT INTO `categorycount`(`CategoryId`, `amount`, `userid`, `categoryno`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $stmt6 = $mysqli->prepare($save_running_records);
        $stmt4 = $mysqli->prepare($save_running_report);
        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($save_running_travel);        
        $stmt5 = $mysqli->prepare($save_new_record);
        $stmt7 = $mysqli->prepare($save_count);


        $stmt6->bind_param('s', $mrecord_old_num);
        $stmt4->bind_param('s', $report_old_num);
        $stmt2->bind_param('s', $travel_old_num);
        $stmt5->bind_param('ssiisssbssssssiii', $reportName, $report_number, $euser, $category_air, $travel_number, $descript, $claim_amount_fare, $filefare, $filefare, $docno_air, $origin, $airline, $destination, $email, $app1, $app2, $app3);
        $stmt7->bind_param('isis', $category_air, $claim_amount_fare, $euser, $mrecord_number);

        if ($stmt5->execute() == false){
            echo 'Fifth query failed: ' . $mysqli->error;
                } else {
                    if ($stmt2->execute() == false){
                    echo 'gl B query failed: ' . $mysqli->error;    
                    } else {
                        if ($stmt4->execute() == false){
                            echo 'gl B query failed: ' . $mysqli->error;
                        } else {
                            if ($stmt7->execute() == false) {
                                echo 'gl B query failed: ' . $mysqli->error;
                            } else {
                                    if($stmt6->execute() == false){
                                        echo 'gl C query failed: ' . $mysqli->error;
                                    }
                                $stmt6->close();
                                }
                            $stmt7->close();
                            }
                        $stmt4->close();
                        }
                    $stmt2->close();    
                }
            $stmt5->close();
        }
    }
```

[airfare table image](http://prntscr.com/fk5687)
[others expenses table image](http://prntscr.com/fk56dh)

My current problem is now how to handle if table in other expense tab is empty? because when i try to submit form and fill in all the input except for the others expense tab table which i let it empty. when i submit the form, the empty row in other expense tab table is insert in database table as well..

Comment: *"I have a form"* - I see. Can you update your post to include that and the relevant code?

Comment: Wouldn't be related to your earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/q/44403801/1415724 would it?

Comment: i re-edit my post with the code and some images

Comment: I will ask again: Wouldn't be related to your earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/q/44403801/1415724 would it? You haven't responded to that, just my first comment.

Comment: yes fred it related to it. but non of people give me a clue about that post. as you can see theres no one reply or comment at my post. and i try to re-create new topic with simple explaination.

Comment: Well, that is a lot of code. See if error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and checking for errors on the queries `mysqli_error($mysqli)` picks up anything. You also didn't include the HTML for this, so that could also be faling.

Comment: yes i know. but my main question is. is that how we submit a form if there are two table inside the forms? And the table is dynamic table which able to add table row.

Comment: Fred, i just put the submit form code only. i didnt include the html for this. if i include it should be very long code. Thats why i include the image link at bottom of the code above. so that you have the visual. two image showing two different tab which contain two different table but it will be insert in same database table.

Comment: My current problem is now how to handle if table in other expense tab is empty? because when i try to submit form and fill in all the input except for the others expense tab table which i let it empty. when i submit the form, the empty row in other expense tab table is insert in database table as well.. i try to count the merchant _post and putthe condition under the for loop for the merchant(is attribut or input under tha other expense tab table). so i put the condition if !empty merchant(insert)